# T5 page request return blank layout under heavy load test

Tags: jvm, weblogic, tapestry, load-testing

I recently have an application develop with tapestry 5.1 deploy on Weblogic + oracle database. The pages work well under normal usage but went nuts after stress testing.

I am using hibernate + spring security module from tapestry on the web page login, and ramp up 1000 users on the login process. Upon processing 500 users login, the application seems to be "exhausted" and only response the bare layout as html on all requests(regardless if the request on any page, css, js  and etc).

Also notice the javascript onDomLoaded is now empty:

```
Tapestry.onDOMLoaded(function() {
});
```

Which should normally:

```
Tapestry.onDOMLoaded(function() {
Tapestry.init({
  "linkZone":[["forgotPassword","loginZone","/duc/login.forgotpassword"]],
  "zone":[{"update":"show","element":"loginZone"}]});
});
```

Weirdly, when the XDebug on JVM is set, the problem seems to be solved. Further analysis on the server, it only use nearly 50% of cpu, 40% or memory, 40 connections to the database whilst the load test.

Anyone have any idea?

Helps are much appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried asking the tapestry mailing list?

Comment: how reproducible is the problem? ie if you run the test 10 times does it happen 10 times? if you run in debug mode 10 times does it never occur?

Answer (score 3):

Please check the mailing list .. this was resolved as an OutOfMemory error, not really related to Tapestry at all.

Answer (score 1):

take out `-XX:+UseCompressedOops` from your vm arguments! [;)](http://tapestry.1045711.n5.nabble.com/T5-page-request-return-blank-layout-under-heavy-load-test-td3277134.html#a3278183)